# jQuery: check if text exists in another element

Tags: text, jquery

Using jQuery, I want to check if the text of a link I'm clicking is present in another element on the page. The text in the other element is added dynamically and isn't present on the page initially.

So far I have this:

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var seed = $(this).text();
    if ($("#seeds:has(" + seed + ")")){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        // other code
    }
});
```

But for some reason, I always get the "already have it" alert even if the text of the `#results a` link isn't present in the `#seeds` `<div>`. What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: using `:contains` instead of `:has`, as suggested, works for the most part...except if `#seeds` contains a string that's a superset of the text in the `#results` anchor.

For example, if `#seeds` contains the text `Americana` and the `#results` anchor's text is `America`, I will still get the "already have it" alert. I want the alert to appear only for an exact match. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:contains()` instead of `:has()`:

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var seed = $(this).text();
    if ($("#seeds:contains(" + seed + ")").length){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        // other code
    }
});
```

This checks if the `#seeds` element contains the text that the link clicked contains.

If you want to find any elements that are descendants of the `#seeds` element:

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var seed = $(this).text();
    if ($("#seeds").find(":contains(" + seed + ")").length){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        // other code
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wE3p/

Notice that I am checking the `length` of the returned set of elements, if there are no elements then zero will be returned and the `if` statement will resolve to false, if there are any elements then it will resolve `truthily`.

Also note that `:contains()` is case-sensitive: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

### Side-Note

If you are using jQuery 1.4.2 or greater then you can use `.delegate()` rather than `.live()`.  The main benefit to `.delegate()` is that you can select your root element. So if for instance, `#results`, is always present in the DOM then you can use it as the root element rather than the `document` element (which is what `.live()` does):

```
//it's this easy to change to `.delegate()`
$("#results").delegate("a", "click", function(event){
    var seed = $(this).text();
    if ($("#seeds").find(":contains(" + seed + ")").length){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        // other code
    }
});
```

If `#results` is added to the DOM dynamically then you can find it's parent and use it as the root element (... as long as it persists in the DOM).

### Update

If you want to only match the exact text of the link then you can iterate through the descendant elements of the `#results` element and check the text of each element:

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var seed  = $(this).text(),
        found = false;
    $.each($('#seeds').find('*'), function () {
        if ($(this).text() == seed) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (found){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        alert('that\'s new');
    }
    return false;
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wE3p/1/

You can also use RegExp to match the value:

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var regexp = new RegExp("^(" + $(this).text() + ")$", "i"),
        found  = false;
    $.each($('#seeds').find('*'), function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(regexp) > -1) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (found){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        alert('that\'s new');
    }
    return false;
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wE3p/2/

The important part here is the creation of the RegExp: `var regexp = new RegExp("^(" + $(this).text() + ")$", "i")`. Notice the `i` flag which sets the RegExp to search case-insensitive. Also the `^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end, so this look to see if the current text being checked is the exact same string as the search term (except that it's case-insensitive).

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work for me in all cases - see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:contains()` instead of `:has()` and check for length property because jQuery always gives an object.

`:has(selector)` takes selector as input and looks for element which match selector where as `:contains(text)` takes the text to check for within elements text content and select them.

```
$("#results a").live("click", function(event){
    var seed = $(this).text();
    if ($("#seeds:contains(" + seed + ")").length){
        alert("already have it");
    }
    else {
        // other code
    }
});
```