# check if text exist then run function

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
</script>
```

pretty much I would like to run a function instead of changing the css attributes of the div.
for example if there is a div that contain the name John execute `$(selector).click();`

any ideas ?

Comment: an if statement wont do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: check if text exists in another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300123/jquery-check-if-text-exists-in-another-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if selected element exists get the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property and make sure it is more than `0`:

```
if ($('div:contains("John")').length) {
    // element exists
}
```

Comment: thanks VisioN I was unsure about the syntax I am trying it out

Answer (score 2):

check div length should not be null

```
if ($('div:contains("John")').length>0) {
    // your script here
}
```